# attribute update clears some attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

We have done some updates to Magento. We are now working on CE 1.9.1.0.
But we select some product(s) and then go to the upper right corner and click 'Update Attributes' in the Actions dropdown and update one or more attributes it clears the attributes color, size and two custom attributes.

Do you have any idea what is going on? or how to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by "do an attribute update"? Show some code.

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Marius. I don't have a code for you. Sorry. But we select the product(s) and then go to the upper right corner and click 'Update Attributes' in the Actions dropdown.

Comment: You might want to add your comment to the question to make it clearer for everyone.